# Getting content from LocalStorage & put it back into TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am building a daily planner and I know I am logging the right data and the right keys into local storage but I can't figure out how to get it back out!

my HTML looks like the following and i have this set up from 8am to 5pm. They are all the same. Local storage key is the time block (8,9,10 etc) and the value is that time blocks text

```
<tr id="8-text" class="tasks">
        <th class="TOD" style="padding-top: 24px" scope="row">8AM</th>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="textarea" class="toDo" colspan="2">
          local storage value goes here
        </td>
        <td id="8" class="saveBtn"> 
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
            <svg class="save" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="white" class="bi bi-lock" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M8 1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v4H6V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2zm3 6V3a3 3 0 0 0-6 0v4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v5a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zM5 8h6a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v5a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V9a1 1 0 0 1 1-1z"/>
            </svg>
          </button> 
        </tr>
```

I am setting it with this query function

```
 $("button").on("click", function(){

timeKey = $(this).parent().attr("id")
// console.log(timeKey)

value = $(this).closest("tr");
valueText = value.find("td:eq(0)").text();
// console.log(valueText)

block = localStorage.setItem(timeKey, JSON.stringify(valueText))
```

})

Comment: You have text between two `td`s and the second td is not closed.

Comment: TR inside DIV? oh nonono TR is only allowed inside `<table>` or better say: `<thead>`, `<tbody>` , `<tfoot>`

Comment: *local storage value goes here* ? no. No contextual content is allowed inside a `<tr>` besides `<th>` or `<td>` Elements.